# How to run a Hadoop DFSIO MapReduce benchmark test in Docker?

Tags: docker, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Could you please help me run this HDFS benchmarking using TestDFSIO?

I have a hadoop cluster created with 4 live data nodes and 1 checkpoint node and am trying to write 10 files (100 MB each) using the following command in a Docker namenode container:

```
yarn jar $MAPRED_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-*-tests.jar TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 10 -fileSize 100
```

However, the following error loop keeps appearing:

```
2020-06-15 00:05:01,756 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: TestDFSIO.1.8
2020-06-15 00:05:01,765 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: nrFiles = 10
2020-06-15 00:05:01,765 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: nrBytes (MB) = 100.0
2020-06-15 00:05:01,766 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: bufferSize = 1000000
2020-06-15 00:05:01,766 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: baseDir = /benchmarks/TestDFSIO
2020-06-15 00:05:04,924 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: creating control file: 104857600 bytes, 10 files
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /benchmarks/TestDFSIO/io_control. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 78 has reached the threshold 0,9990 of total blocks 78. The minimum number of live datanodes is not required. In safe mode extension. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 1 seconds. NamenodeHostName:namenode
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.newSafemodeException(FSNamesystem.java:1476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:3084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.delete(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:1609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:946)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:943)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.createControlFile(TestDFSIO.java:309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.run(TestDFSIO.java:868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.main(TestDFSIO.java:743)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.run(MapredTestDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.main(MapredTestDriver.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot delete /benchmarks/TestDFSIO/io_control. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 78 has reached the threshold 0,9990 of total blocks 78. The minimum number of live datanodes is not required. In safe mode extension. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 1 seconds. NamenodeHostName:namenode
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.newSafemodeException(FSNamesystem.java:1476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:3084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.delete(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:1607)
    ... 23 more
hdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ hdfs --daemon stop namenode^[[A^[[Dhdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/yarn --daemon stop resourcemanagerhdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ hdfs --daemon start namenodehdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ yarn --daemon stop resourcemanager
hdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ yarn jar $MAPRED_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-*-tests.jar TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 10 -fileSize 100
2020-06-15 00:06:29,250 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: TestDFSIO.1.8
2020-06-15 00:06:29,261 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: nrFiles = 10
2020-06-15 00:06:29,261 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: nrBytes (MB) = 100.0
2020-06-15 00:06:29,262 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: bufferSize = 1000000
2020-06-15 00:06:29,262 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: baseDir = /benchmarks/TestDFSIO
2020-06-15 00:06:31,091 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: creating control file: 104857600 bytes, 10 files
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /benchmarks/TestDFSIO/io_control. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 78 has reached the threshold 0,9990 of total blocks 78. The minimum number of live datanodes is not required. In safe mode extension. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 22 seconds. NamenodeHostName:namenode
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.newSafemodeException(FSNamesystem.java:1476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:3084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.delete(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:1609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:946)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:943)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.createControlFile(TestDFSIO.java:309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.run(TestDFSIO.java:868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.main(TestDFSIO.java:743)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.run(MapredTestDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.main(MapredTestDriver.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Cannot delete /benchmarks/TestDFSIO/io_control. Name node is in safe mode.
The reported blocks 78 has reached the threshold 0,9990 of total blocks 78. The minimum number of live datanodes is not required. In safe mode extension. Safe mode will be turned off automatically in 22 seconds. NamenodeHostName:namenode
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.newSafemodeException(FSNamesystem.java:1476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkNameNodeSafeMode(FSNamesystem.java:1463)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:3084)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.delete(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:1607)
    ... 23 more
hdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ hdfs --daemon start namenode
namenode is running as process 10517.  Stop it first.
hdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ hdfs --daemon stop namenode
hdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ yarn --daemon stop resourcemanager
hdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ hdfs --daemon start namenode
hdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ yarn --daemon start resourcemanager
hdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ export MAPRED_EXAMPLES=$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce
hdadmin@namenode:~/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ yarn jar $MAPRED_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-*-tests.jar TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 10 -fileSize 100
2020-06-15 00:14:38,119 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: TestDFSIO.1.8
2020-06-15 00:14:38,123 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: nrFiles = 10
2020-06-15 00:14:38,124 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: nrBytes (MB) = 100.0
2020-06-15 00:14:38,124 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: bufferSize = 1000000
2020-06-15 00:14:38,124 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: baseDir = /benchmarks/TestDFSIO
2020-06-15 00:14:40,975 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: creating control file: 104857600 bytes, 10 files
2020-06-15 00:14:41,996 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:45,521 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:45,700 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:46,387 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:46,571 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:46,807 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:47,606 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:47,763 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:47,955 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:48,052 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:48,189 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: created control files for: 10 files
2020-06-15 00:14:49,015 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032
2020-06-15 00:14:50,046 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at timelineserver/172.18.0.2:10200
2020-06-15 00:14:50,165 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032
2020-06-15 00:14:50,166 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at timelineserver/172.18.0.2:10200
2020-06-15 00:14:50,750 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hdadmin/.staging/job_1592172809365_0001
2020-06-15 00:14:50,996 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:51,419 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 10
2020-06-15 00:14:51,547 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:51,750 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:51,805 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:10
2020-06-15 00:14:52,969 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-06-15 00:14:53,150 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1592172809365_0001
2020-06-15 00:14:53,151 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2020-06-15 00:14:53,679 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2020-06-15 00:14:53,680 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2020-06-15 00:14:55,014 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1592172809365_0001
2020-06-15 00:14:55,398 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://resourcemanager:8088/proxy/application_1592172809365_0001/
2020-06-15 00:14:55,421 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1592172809365_0001
2020-06-15 00:18:23,317 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1592172809365_0001 running in uber mode : false
2020-06-15 00:18:23,492 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2020-06-15 00:30:16,725 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1592172809365_0001_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1592172809365_0001_m_000001_0 Timed out after 600 secs
2020-06-15 00:30:16,759 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1592172809365_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1592172809365_0001_m_000000_0 Timed out after 600 secs
2020-06-15 00:48:48,482 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:49,488 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:50,489 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:51,493 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:52,496 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:53,500 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:54,503 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:55,505 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:56,509 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:57,511 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-06-15 00:48:58,359 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: java.net.ConnectException: Call From namenode/172.18.0.7 to resourcemanager:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused, while invoking ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getApplicationReport over null. Trying to failover immediately.
2020-06-15 00:48:59,361 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: resourcemanager/172.18.0.7:8032.
java.io.IOException: Call From namenode/172.18.0.7 to resourcemanager:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getTaskCompletionEvents(ClientServiceDelegate.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getTaskCompletionEvents(YARNRunner.java:878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$6.run(Job.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$6.run(Job.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskCompletionEvents(Job.java:729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.monitorAndPrintJob(Job.java:1652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$NetworkedJob.monitorAndPrintJob(JobClient.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.monitorAndPrintJob(JobClient.java:895)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:875)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.runIOTest(TestDFSIO.java:476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.writeTest(TestDFSIO.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.run(TestDFSIO.java:872)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO.main(TestDFSIO.java:743)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.run(MapredTestDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.test.MapredTestDriver.main(MapredTestDriver.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

It is worth mentioning that the same job with filesize 10 MB was completed succesfully.

What should I do to run this job successfully?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Besides Namenode and Data Nodes, you also need Resource Manager and Node Managers setup on you cluster in order to run YARN application, which are missing according to your exception.

You can refer to this (https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop) project for an example of how to setup Hadoop cluster in Docker.